# Qual a melhor maneira para se definir a altura de um iframe em 100%?

Tags: html, css

Pessoal qual seria a melhor maneira pra se definir a altura de um `iframe` em 100%? Já tentei com `Height=100%` propriedade do próprio `HTML` (embora não seja mais aconselhável depois do `HTML5` e do próprio `CSS`), e também tentei definir uma folha de estilo `height:100%;`.

Já procurei no fórum mas não encontrei nenhuma solução semelhante.

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda, mas se você iniciar sua folha de estilo com html, body { height: 100%} o restante dos elementos vão entender que há uma porcentagem relativa internamente.

Comment: Era isso mesmo @IvanFerrer eu inclusive pesquisei em inglês e encontrei a solução que tentava há muito tempo resolver, não sabia dessa particularidade do html, body ter que está como 100%. Sem isso não funcionava, inclusive coloquei uma resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a solução no próprio fórum internacional: 
[How to set the iframe height & width to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027068/how-to-set-the-iframe-height-width-to-100)

A melhor solução é através de CSS,  mas uma observação importante é que é necessário modificar o valor da tag `html` e `body` também com `height` 100%, e a própria `position` influencia também, todas menos a `relative` funcionam.

O código seria assim:

```css
html,body        {height:100%;}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: O problema agora é se a `position` for `relative` não está funcionando.